# Can I save my progress from borderlands 2 to the game of the year edition?

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands-2

I have the regular Borderlands 2 edition and I am thinking about buying the Game of the year edition, so I can have all the DLC's. If I buy the GOTY edition, will I be able to save my character and progress from the regular edition? If so, how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: What system are you playing on?

Comment: I play on xbox 360

Answer (score 3):

Your original Borderlands 2 saves will work in the GOTY and vice-versa. In fact, the GOTY edition is simply the original game with [a separate "install" disc](http://www.amazon.com/review/R1XODZR5MNPVD6/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00ERDGMT4&nodeID=468642&store=videogames) bundled for the DLC.

Answer (score 0):

GOTY edition of Borderlands 2 and the original edition of Borderlands 2 use the same file save system. This means that buying the GOTY edition will not change any of your saves. If anything it will increase the ability to level them up.